# Indexing set for partition

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

On page 3/(4) of Dummit&Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (3rd ed.):

> (Let $A$ be a nonempty set) A *partition* of $A$ is any collection $\{A_i\lvert i\in I\}$ of nonempty subsets of $A$ ($I$ some indexing set) such that (**a**) $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, and (**b**) $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$, for all $i,j\in I$ with $i\neq j$. i.e., $A$ is the disjoint union of the sets in the partition.

- May I ask, by the word *indexing* in this context, if the indexing set can contain infinitely many elements? In particular, can it contain uncountably many elements? (The answer to this question is probably "yes")
- Furthermore, can the function from $I$ to those nonempty subsets of $A$ (i.e. the process of indexing) not be injective? More importantly, are there cases where we intentionally want it not to be injective? And why? [For this question we shall modify the definition (**b**) to "$A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$, for all $A_i,A_j\in A$ with $A_i\neq A_j$"]

Some stranger questions:

- Am I allowed to have $I=A$? If so, is it meaningful? (A kind of self-indexing?)
- Is that possible, by any chance, to have some partition of some set being unable to be indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general an indexing set can be any set at all. Yes, one member of a partition can have more than one index, though the default would be an injective map. Yes, it’s possible to index a partition of $A$ by $A$ itself: if $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $A$, for each $a\in A$ let $A_a$ be the unique member of $\mathscr{P}$ containing $a$. In this case the indexing is clearly not injective unless $\mathscr{P}$ is the partition of $A$ into singletons. This of course shows that every partition can be indexed. In fact, every partition can be injectively indexed, since it can trivially be indexed by itself: the function is $$f:\mathscr{P}\to\mathscr{P}:P\mapsto P\,,$$ or, in the notation of Dummit & Foote’s definition, $A_P=P$ for each $P\in\mathscr{P}$. This is pretty pointless, but it is technically an indexing of the partition.

I dislike that definition, because, as some of what I’ve written may suggest, the indexing is completely unnecessary. A partition $\mathscr{P}$ of a non-empty set $A$ is simply a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty subsets of $A$ such that $\bigcup\mathscr{P}=A$. Any surjective function $f$ from a set $I$ to $\mathscr{P}$ can then be used to index $\mathscr{P}$: for each $i\in I$ we have $P_i=f(i)$.